# Compare values without regard to address using RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

Using RSpec, I would like to check if the values of two custom objects are the same.

Suppose I have a `Person` class that has a `name` and `age` attribute, and instantiate two objects.

```
person_1 = Person.new(name: 'Jack', age: 20)
person_2 = Person.new(name: 'Jack', age: 20)
```

To see if they have all the same attributes, I cannot use `eq` matcher because they are two different objects.

Given that I am not using ActiveRecord, is there a way to do so without comparing all individual attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two main ways of doing what you want.

You can either implement [a custom matcher](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/custom-matchers) or [override the == method](http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/ruby-equality-and-object-comparison/) on the `Person` class. Second is nice, because you can then use the equality in other places, even outside of tests. First method is good if what you are comparing is very specific (e.g. you don't care for all person's attributes in a particular test).

Answer (score 0):

It should help you:

```
https://github.com/TylerRick/active_record_ignored_attributes

a = Address.new(address: 'B St.')
b = Address.new(address: 'B St.')
a.same_as?(b) # => true

a = Address.new(address: 'B St.')
b = Address.new(address: 'Nowhere Road')
a.same_as?(b) # => false
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks great. But I am not using ActiveRecord at the moment.

Comment: You can add this gem it into test group in gem file